# Angular 2 Reading List with ngFor on View?

Tags: angularjs, list, cordova, ionic2, ngfor

I'm trying List reading from WebApi with ngFor but it doesn't work for me.

```
export class MembershipPage {

memberships: any = [];


constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public authservice: AuthService) {

}


ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.authservice.getmembers().then(
        data => {
            this.memberships.push(data);

        }
    );
}
```

and i'am calling from view like this`

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let member of memberships">{{member.Name}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

[image]

Getting my data [Object object] on my ion-item. What's the problem? I don't understand.

Comment: Is there any error message? Possible your `member` object do not have `name` propertive.

Comment: There isn't an error message and yes i have name property in my list.

Comment: How does your `data` look like? Try `console.log(data)` to see it.

Comment: edit question with data array content. You can see it by adding `console.log(data)` in to 
`data => {
            this.memberships.push(data);}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
     this.authservice.getmembers().then( data => {
         this.memberships = data;
     } ); 
 }
```